# Freehand digitzing issues in QField

Tags: qfield, digitizing

On my fieldwork project I must be able to draw freehand lines in QField.
So far I have made it work with connected mouse. When using stylus, I can activate the freehand editing button (actually sometimes can, sometimes I must enable-disable editing of layer several times before it starts to work). But even if freehand digitizing is enabled I can create a line by adding nodes.

Can it be problem of stylus I use? It's simple battery loaded without bluetooth or pressure sensitivity. But it works well to draw lines in drawing apps.

Tried on Samsung Galaxy S22 Ultra and Google Pixel 6 with QField ver 2.8.5

Answer (score 0):

I wish I could do freehand digitizong on my smartphone too, but my experience so far is that no stylus pen (I've tried some, the Zspeed K811 among them) works with my Fairphone 3+ screen. I guess my screen is not compatible with any type of stylus pen at all.